# How to list the products under each category in sql? side by side

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm a bit of a beginner in sql and I need your help.
I'm sorry that I don't know if the question is correct.

now the code gives this;

```
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
|      id | CompanyId| DealId      | price      |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
|       1 | 1        | 1           | 100        | 
|       2 | 1        | 2           | 50         | 
|       3 | 1        | 3           | 25         |
|       4 | 2        | 1           | 1000       |
|       5 | 2        | 2           | 2000       |
|       6 | 2        | 3           | 2500       |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
```

but this is what i want;

```
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
|      id | companyId| DealName1   | DealName2  | DealName3  |  |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
|       1 |  1       | 100         | 50         |   25       |  |
|       2 |  2       | 1000        | 2000       |   2500     |  |
|       3 |  3       | value       | value      |   value    |  |
|       4 |  4       | value       | value      |   value    |  |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
```

Comment: You're looking for a conditional aggregation or PIVOT.

Comment: please take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and add tables and the data where he result should be like you want it

Comment: Where does company #3 come from?

Comment: @TheImpaler I have about 10000+ companies and it comes from the company table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  CompanyId 
       ,[1] as DealName1
       ,[2] as DealName2
       ,[3] as DealName3
     
from   (select CompanyId, DealId, price from   t) t
pivot  (sum(price) for DealId in([1],[2],[3])) p
```

| CompanyId | DealName1 | DealName2 | DealName3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 50 | 25 |
| 2 | 1000 | 2000 | 2500 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0fAiGF1Z)

Comment: I can't open a new topic. I have one last question for you. Would you like to help? https://dbfiddle.uk/x4CsrVtb

Comment: Sure. Go ahead.

Comment: Can you see the link split?

Comment: @Cenk when you pivot there is an assumed groupings. Without diving too dip into it here are two solutions (scroll down). One without PayingCompanies and one with. Also, when you added all the numbers for `total` you needed to get rid of all the `nulls` like you did in the select. I just nested it so I won't have to write all of it down. Shouldn't make any difference in execution. Let me know if you have any questions: https://dbfiddle.uk/yK9JlycB

Comment: Thank you very, very much indeed.
I will add 6 more tables on it. This will make my job a lot easier. I'm writing a store procedure and I still have a lot to learn. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Anytime. Feel free to email me if you need. Danny.slor@gmail.com